# How to get global tab-width in spacemacs?

Tags: emacs, coffeescript

Brand new to emacs and spacemacs. Hoping to learn the ropes.

I have added the following lines to my `.spacemacs` file:

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq-default tab-width 2)
(setq-default c-basic-offset 2)
(setq indent-line-function 'insert-tab)

;; Coffeescript specific tabbing requirements
(custom-set-variables '(coffee-tab-width 2))
```

It seems to work on every file but coffeescript files. For some reason, even with these settings, coffeescript files are still forced into tab-width 4.

Is there something I’m missing here? Not even sure how to debug this. The `.spacemacs` file loads fine.

Comment: The maintainer of the spacemacs package frequents https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/ and emacs.stackexchange.com -- if you don't get a response in the near future, consider posting over there and maybe cancelling this one (so no one complains about cross-posting).

Comment: Posting here is fine. If this stackexchange doesn't already have an answer, this question/answer is then valuable.